# How to create a native query in which you call a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

My question is mainly that I cannot find a solution on how to use a stored procedure through the Direct Query data connectivity method for Power BI, that is, I want to make a report in Power BI using Direct Query for its data set it's in a stored procedure.

Reading and consulting for several days I have found a possible solution (here they will tell me if it is the most optimal for my case) is to create a native query which calls the stored procedure, this in order to make use not of the stored procedure but of the native query from Power BI.

The stored procedure that I have to do the native query as I am thinking is the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TravelsCustomers]
    @TypeOp int = 0,
    @Customer varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT  
        Estatus,
        ClaveCustomer
        Lote,
        Address,
        OC
    INTO
        #Response
    FROM    
        TravelVw V
    WHERE   
        Estatus = 'PROGRESS'
        AND TypeOp = CASE 
                         WHEN @TypeOp = 0 THEN TypeOp
                         WHEN @TypeOp = 1 THEN 'FLASH'
                         WHEN @TypeOp = 2 THEN 'SMALL'
                     END
        AND ISNULL(@Customer, '0') IN ('0', ClaveCustomer)  
        AND TypeOp != 'SALE'

    SELECT
        V.*, 
        I2.Coment, I2.MODIFIEDBY, I2.CreatedDateTime
    FROM
        #Response V
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT 
             I.Travel, 
             ISNULL(I.Coment, '-') Coment,
             I.ModifiedBy,
             DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), I.CreatedDateTime) CreatedDateTime
         FROM
             dbo.Travel I 
         WHERE
             I.CREATEDDATETIME = (SELECT MAX(CREATEDDATETIME) 
                                  FROM dbo.I3
                                  WHERE I.Travel = I3.Travel)
        ) I2 ON V.Travel = I2.Travel
END
```

Here I would like to have your support either to generate the native query or to give me a better option regarding the use of stored procedures with Direct Query from Power BI.

Comment: I am 99% sure that DirectQuery + stored procedures is not going to work.

Comment: Can you not just do `EXEC TravelsCustomers...`? Side note: this query could do with optimization. For example, better to do `AND (@TypeOp = 0 OR TypeOp = CASE                          WHEN @TypeOp = 1 THEN 'FLASH' WHEN @TypeOp = 2 THEN 'SMALL' END)` and better to do `AND (@Customer IS NULL OR ClaveCustomer = @Customer)`

Comment: Why the #temp table? The stored procedure could be rewritten as a table-valued function, or a view, both of which can be consumed by DirectQuery.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I know that unfortunately it is not possible, but there are some ways to do it either with views or with SQL functions that seem to work like procedures and apparently are consumed by means of a select, it is one of the possible solutions that I have found. Have you tried doing any of these?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Is there a way that I can rewrite the stored procedure as a table-valued function or a view to later be consumed by DirectQuery in PBI?

Comment: @Charlieface In the case of DirectQuery I am not allowed to just execute the procedure the way you propose

Comment: Put the first query inside the second `FROM (SELECT Estatus, ...) V LEFT JOIN...`, place `CREATE VIEW` at the beginning of the `SELECT`  and make a view out of it

Comment: @Charlieface Could you please give me an example based on my question to validate your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a table-valued function, which you should be able to access using DirectQuery

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[TravelsCustomers]
(
    @TypeOp int = 0,
    @Customer varchar(50)
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

    SELECT
        V.*, 
        I2.Coment, I2.MODIFIEDBY, I2.CreatedDateTime
    FROM (
        SELECT  
            Estatus,
            ClaveCustomer
            Lote,
            Address,
            OC
        FROM    
            TravelVw V
        WHERE   
            Estatus = 'PROGRESS'
            AND (@TypeOp = 0 OR TypeOp = CASE 
                         WHEN @TypeOp = 1 THEN 'FLASH'
                         WHEN @TypeOp = 2 THEN 'SMALL'
                     END)
            AND (@CustomerIS NULL OR ClaveCustomer = @Customer)
            AND TypeOp != 'SALE'
        ) V
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT 
             I.Travel, 
             ISNULL(I.Coment, '-') Coment,
             I.ModifiedBy,
             DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), I.CreatedDateTime) CreatedDateTime
         FROM
             dbo.Travel I 
         WHERE
             I.CREATEDDATETIME = (SELECT MAX(CREATEDDATETIME) 
                                  FROM dbo.I3
                                  WHERE I.Travel = I3.Travel)
        ) I2 ON V.Travel = I2.Travel;

GO
```

Comment: When making use of the function from Power Bi by Direct Query and when selecting the function at the end of the tables, I do not get any data in the table, any suggestions or changes that I can make? Or is there some other way to call the newly created function from Power BI?

Comment: It should have given you a result if there was no errors. Based on the changes I made, just guessing: what parameters are you passing in